# Trouble composing jsonpath query to return first object of a filtered array

Tags: jsonpath

Using the [ashphy json path evaluator](http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator/), and the following JSON:

```
{ "store": {
    "book": [ 
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to write a query that filters category, e.g. "fiction", and then return only the first element.  I can't quite seem to figure it out.

For example, `$..book[?(@.category == "fiction")]`, will return an array of 3 books, but I just want the first book:

```
{ "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      }
```

Can it be done??  The obvious thing seemed to be to add an "[0]" to the end, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I examined the analytics site (Note: this is from testing http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator/):

[image]

Placing the [0] index look up DOES work. The site merely accepts what will go inside the argument of jsonPath(jsonObj, query string) thus the index reference must go outside this evaluation which the site does not do.

```
jsonPath(foo, '$..book[?(@.category == "fiction")]')[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am looking for - the jsonPath returns an array, and the [0] accesses the first element of the array.  I need the jsonPath to filter one element.  I don't have direct access to the array.